# Installing Elementary OS without USB drive or DVD

Tags: usb, install

I'm running Elementary OS on my Macbook from an external USB drive but I thought about installing it on a thumbdrive. Is there a way to install Elementary OS from my current install so that I can just run it (while booted into EOS) rather than creating a boot drive from the .ISO etc?

Comment: Is this external usb drive a live version or full install?

Comment: This is a full install. I've downloaded the .ISO and mounted it (in EOS) but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to run the install process without booting from an installer image.

Comment: Are you avoiding a reboot or this is because you don't want to burn the installer iso on a separate device.

Comment: Just to save having to burn the installer onto another device really. Seemed like it should be possible from within EOS, a bit like installing OS X, the way the installer downloads and then you can run it from within OS X.

Comment: I don't think such an installer exist in Elementary. So I am assuming rebooting your existing install is not an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that comes to my mind is using the UNetbootin `Hard Disk Install Mode`. You can find the details here on [UNetbootin Sourceforge page](https://sourceforge.net/p/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes/). I would also refer you to [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484434/install-ubuntu-without-cd-and-usb-how) for step by step process.

I think the hard disk here can be an empty partition on hard disk on the mac book or a new partition on your external usb installation, if you don't want to mess with your mac book hard disk.

Latest UNetbootin can be installed via following commands,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```